# How to minimize wrt one set of parameters and maximize wrt other set of parameters simultaneously in a training loop in pytorch?

Tags: optimization, pytorch, minimax

I have a loss function that includes two sets of parameters to learn. One is a matrix, wrt which I want to maximize the loss, other is the set of parameters for logistic regression, wrt which I want to minimize the loss.
In pytorch whenever I use loss.backward(), the loss is minimized wrt both sets of parameters and (-loss).backward() maximizes wrt both. How do I do minimax optimization wrt the sets of parameters in pytorch?
Tensorflow probably has this concept of gradient_tape and tape.watch() concept. What's the alternative in pytorch?

Comment: Have you tried using the gradient reversal or some similar ideas? I can explain that in an answer if you haven't tried that already.

Comment: No I haven't tried that yet. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Basically, say I have f(X,Y), where X is one set of variables and Y is the other. Now this f(X,Y) can't be broken into f1(X)+f2(Y), otherwise it would have been an easy task. I have to minimize f(X,Y) wrt X and maximize wrt Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the gradient reversal idea from https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.7495.

But the crux of the idea is this: you have some loss function l(X,Y) where X and Y are parameters. Now you want to update X to minimize loss and update Y to maximize loss, which can be seen as minimizing -l(X,Y).

Essentially you want to update parameters X with dl/dX and Y with d(-l)/dY = -dl/dy. You can do this by doing a backpropagation step, modifying the gradients of Y, and applying the update. In pytorch terms, that would be:

```
loss = compute_loss()
loss.backward()
# modify gradients of Y
Y.grad.data = -Y.grad.data
optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero_grad()
```

Comment: Oh my god! This seems so simple!
Thanks a lot! You've been a saviour!!!

Comment: Glad! I could help. Please accept the answer if it works, that would help others as they would know that it works :)